# Анализ изображения

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо проанализировав изображение, сообщить количество и местоположение ЛИЦ человеков в этом изображении. Нужен как можно более эффективный и корректный алгоритм.

Кто подскажет с чего начать?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Задачка несложная и все это уже давным-давно реализовано в библиотеке OpenCV, у которой есть полностью работоспособный биндинг к C# под названием [**EmguCV.**](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Список реализованных алгоритмов можно найти [**здесь**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition), а пример использования на *(правда, на Java, но суть от этого не меняется)* - [**тут.**](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/60782/)

---

Если хочется попробовать что-то свое, да еще и небесполезное, то можете попробовать изучить и реализовать [другие алгоритмы с референсами,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_detection#References) насколько мне известно, существует несколько интересных статей, датированных 2011 годом.

**Несколько интересных референсов по теме, которые я сам в свое время изучал:**

- [Cao, Z., Yin, Q., Tang, X., Sun, J.: Face recognition with learning based descriptor. CVPR (2010)](http://www.jdl.ac.cn/project/faceId/paperreading/Paper/sfxie_20100430.pdf)
- [Karl B. J. Axnick, Kim C. N: Fast Face Recognition](http://pixel.otago.ac.nz/ipapers/60.pdf)
- [Ion Marques - Face Recognition Algorithms (2010)](http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/uploads/e/eb/PFC-IonMarques.pdf)

*Последняя статья носит роль более-менее современного обзора всех популярных алгоритмов и интересна в первую очередь списком из 125 ссылок на другие работы.*

Comment: Было бы неплохо с ссылками :)

Comment: @megacoder Обновил ответ.

Comment: Но лучше разобраться в EmguCV. Работает довольно быстро, проверено!

Comment: @ArtFeel `EmguCV` работает со скоростью `OpenCV`, поскольку просто маршаллит соответствующий код из `dllки`. *Кстати говоря, если собрать `OpenCV` с `TBB`, то производительность вообще прекрасная получается.*